# How to view crash log of release apk

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have created a release apk in mode

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
```

To run the apk on my test device I upload it using `adb install ...`. When the app crashes, I don't get a log in the `logcat`. Is there some configuration I have to change in android studio so as to see what is causing my `release apk` to crash?

Also I try using crashlytics but crashes arrive once in a while and they take forever to come. It's definitely not real-time, not a by a long shot: sometimes hours.

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. I'd love to dig in more into the delays you're seeing on crash reports showing up. Could you email me at support(at)fabric(dot)io with your app's name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ACRA library: http://www.acra.ch/ You need to call the API functions from your code.  When the app crashes, the device will ask the user (you, if you are testing on your device) where to send the stack trace. It's a great tool.

Comment: This looks interesting. I am still looking into it.